# Apache rewrite to save Get parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having single script to render tons of catalogs (`/home/catalogues.php`). And rewrite next rewrite rules to redirect and render those catalogs correctly

```
RewriteRule ^supplies/.* catalogues.php?$1
RewriteRule ^hardware/.* catalogues.php?$1
```

So when I'm having such URL

```
/supplies/cartridges/?Brand%5B%5D=HP&Brand%5B%5D=HP&Type%5B%5D=Mono&page=2
```

GET parameter is empty. It is fixed when form action is redirected directly to /home/catalogues.php But this breaks rendering of a page and connection to DB as tablename is passed through URL either. Seems that is quite a simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must add the Query String Append flag after the Rule: `[QSA]`

Example:

```
 RewriteRule ^supplies/.* catalogues.php?$1 [QSA]
 RewriteRule ^hardware/.* catalogues.php?$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was so easy ^_^